# HTML5 Video not displaying on Mobile Devices?

Tags: html, video, mobile, html5-video

I am attempting to display text on top of a video background. I have used simple HTML5 and CSS to do this. My code works great for desktop sites using Chrome, Safari and Firefox, but when a user views the page on an Android or iPhone device... only the text shows up and the video refuses to play (I am testing on an iPhone 6s Plus and a Samsung S5).

Here is a live preview of the page in question:  http://buzzanimatedvideos.com/video-test/

And here is the CSS & HTML I am using:

```css
   .header-unit {
      background: #fff;
      border: 0 solid #fff;
      height: 500px;
      border: none;
      position: relative;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto;
   }
   .video_container {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: absolute;
      top: -50%;
      left: -50%;
      width: 200%;
      height: 200%;
   }
   video {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      margin: auto;
      min-height: 50%;
      min-width: 50%;
   }
   .video-overlay {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 999;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto;
   }
   .video-overlay-color {
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0%;
      bottom: 0;
      left: auto;
      right: auto;
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
   }
   .video-overlay-content {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 9999;
      opacity: 1;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 25%;
      bottom: 0;
      left: auto;
      right: auto;
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
   }
   .video-overlay-content h1 {
      max-width: 640px;
      color: #fff;
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 3.1rem;
   }
   .video-overlay-content p {
      margin-top: 1rem;
   }
```

```html
<div class="video-overlay">
   <div class="header-unit">
      <div class="video_container">
         <video poster="/wp-content/themes/buzz/vid/video-still.jpg" preload autoplay loop>
            <source src="http://buzzanimatedvideos.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/BuzzAnimated_HeroBG.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            <source src="http://buzzanimatedvideos.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/BuzzAnimated_HeroBG.webm" type="video/webm" />
            <source src="http://buzzanimatedvideos.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/BuzzAnimated_HeroBG.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
         </video>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="video-overlay-color">
      <div class="video-overlay-content">
         <h1>ANIMATED VIDEOS THAT ENTERTAIN, EXPLAIN & GAIN NEW CUSTOMERS</h1>
         <p><a href="/portfolio/" class="button large-alt">WATCH OUR VIDEOS</a></p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know what the issue is? I have been searching high and low for some type of clue but I have nothing. =/  Thanks for your help!

Comment: none of the mobile browsers support autoplay, you'll need to give those users a play button so they can choose if they want to use their bandwidth/battery

Comment: Awesome. I did not know that. That said, I solved the autoplay on mobile by converting the video into a GIF. I hide the video below 640px and display the GIF instead. The GIF just keeps looping regardless of user input, so it works quite well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awesome. I did not know that. That said, I solved the autoplay on mobile by converting the video into a GIF. I hide the video below 640px and display the GIF instead. The GIF just keeps looping regardless of user input, so it works quite well.